# Why did the composite rate for I bonds issued drop to 6.89% from 9.62% when the Fed has been increasing interest rate?

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, federal-reserve

Why did the composite rate for I bonds issued drop to 6.89% from 9.62% when the Fed has been increasing interest rate? What is the correlation between I bonds rate and Feds fund rate?

Comment: The actual rate of interest for an I bond is a combination of the fixed rate and the inflation rate.

Comment: What are *"I bonds"*? United States *[Series I bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Savings_Bonds#Series_I)*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I Bond rates are linked to **current** inflation (which has been falling since June), while the Fed increases interest rates *in the hope* that inflation decreases more *in the future**.

https://www.rateinflation.com/inflation-rate/usa-inflation-rate/
[image]

Comment: That's the trade-off of I bonds. You give up the promise of a guaranteed rate if return in exchange for the promise that the rate should stay safely above inflation.

Comment: What do you mean by "You give up the promise (what promise?) of a guaranteed rate if return in exchange for the promise that the rate should stay safely above inflation?"

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld most bonds are fixed rate.  You *know* that you will get a specific return for the life of the bond.  Not so with I Bonds and TIPS, which are *variable* rate.

Answer (score 9):

You can look [here](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/files/savings-bonds/i-bond-rate-chart.pdf) for the actual data. The bond pays a fixed rate and adjusts for inflation so that your real return is always exactly equal to the fixed rate. That rate is established by the Secretary of the Treasury for the life of the bond without any published rules and not influenced much by the Fed Funds Rate. For example, it stayed at zero from 2020 until November 2022, although the FED increased rates significantly to 3.75% to 4.00%.

[image]

The values are computed as shown below.
[image]

[This answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154593/109107) explains why the formula

> Composite rate = [Fixed rate + (2 x Semiannual inflation rate) +
> (Fixed rate x Semiannual inflation rate)]

is designed like that.

See [TreasuryDirect](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/savings-bonds/i-bonds/i-bonds-interest-rates/) for details about I bonds.

[This answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154484/109107) shows how the semi-annual inflation rate is computed from CPI-U data.

[This answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154568/109107) replicates the calculation of the current value on the website of TreasuryDirect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed calculation! I just don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer!

Comment: no worries, glad it helped